# Do unique horizontal lifts of path homotopic paths through a point are always path homotopic?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

Let $\pi:E \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle for a Lie group $G$. Let $\omega$ be a connection on the principal bundle. It is a well known fact, that  if a path $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ is path homotopic to $\gamma': [0,1] \rightarrow M$, then parallel transports induced by $\omega$ along $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ coincide.

For the definition of path homotopy, please check (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+groupoid#definiti)

**My question is the following:**

Let $\gamma$ be path homotopic to $\gamma'$. Let $p \in \pi^{-1}(\gamma(0))= \pi^{-1}(\gamma'(0))$ and let $\tilde{\gamma}_{p}:[0,1] \rightarrow E$ and $\tilde{\gamma'}_{p}:[0,1] \rightarrow E$ be the unique horizontal lifts of $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ respectively through p, induced by the connection $\omega$. Is $\tilde{\gamma}_{p}$ always path homotopic to $\tilde{\gamma'}_{p}$?

Comment: Are you assumption ng that the connection is flat? Otherwise, your "fact" is not a fact.

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I am not assuming it is flat. Can you please give me an example where this fact does not holds true?

Comment: Actually, this independence property is equivalent to vanishing of the restricted holonomy group, which, in turn, is equivalent to flatness of the connection. [This theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Ambrose%E2%80%93Singer_theorem) will be discussed in any in-depth differential geometry textbook.

Comment: In the case of a surface, you can see that the holonomy (difference in angles between the parallel transports) is the integral of the curvature over the region bounded by the two paths.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks a lot Sir!

Comment: @TedShifrin Sir, is it an example where this fact does not holds true?

Comment: Just consider parallel translation around a geodesic triangle in the unit sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok Sir, I got it .